# Docker agent with Go

Tags: docker, go, jenkins, alpine-linux

I'm trying to create a Jenkins Docker agent that has Go.
The following is my Dockerfile.

After I build it, if I try: `docker run myimage:0.0.1 go version` returns the Go version, however if I try this, it doesn't find Go at all.

```
docker run --privileged --dns 9.0.128.50 --dns 9.0.130.50 -d -P --name slave myimage:0.0.1
docker ps ## grab the port number
ssh -p PORT_NUMBER jenkins@localhost
```

What am I missing in order to make Go available under the Jenkins user?

```rb
FROM golang:1.11.5-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
bash \
curl \
wget \
git \
openssh \
tar

COPY ssh/*key /etc/ssh/
COPY skel/ /home/jenkins
COPY id_rsa /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY id_rsa.pub /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

RUN addgroup docker \
    && adduser -s /bin/bash -h /home/jenkins -G docker -D jenkins \
    && echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers \
    && echo "jenkins:jenkinspass" | chpasswd \
    && chmod u+s /bin/ping \
    && chown -R jenkins:docker /home/jenkins \
    && mv /etc/profile.d/color_prompt /etc/profile.d/color_prompt.sh \
    && mv /bin/sh /bin/sh.bak \
    && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Standard SSH port
EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. When you connect to your slave using ssh, you cannot run go? Maybe your jenkins user just need to know where go is installed. You need to add go the path variable.

Comment: Why does “apk add git” makes Git available for all users but Go isn’t?

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
docker run myimage:0.0.1 which go
```

You will see that go executable in path `/usr/local/go/bin/go`

If you connect as jenkins user via ssh and run `/usr/local/go/bin/go version` all work as well.

Conclusion:

1. Go installation provided as root user
2. jenkins user added after go installed and haven't `/usr/local/go/bin/go` in his `$PATH` environment variable.

Solution:

1. Add `/usr/local/go/bin/go` to `$PATH` for user jenkins
2. Use go executable with full path.